# SQLite3 strange error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, uitextfield

I have a simple iphone/ipad application... but now, **mysteriously**, when i touch on **any textfield** (in UIWebView or in UIView, *it's the same*), the log console give me this error:

```
2011-01-08 20:47:17.242 App_tab[298:207] sqlite3_prepare 'SELECT name, size, width, height, bpr, format FROM store WHERE key=?' failed: 'no such table: store' (1)  
2011-01-08 20:47:17.474 App_tab[298:207] sqlite3_prepare 'INSERT INTO store VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' failed: 'no such table: store' (1)  
2011-01-08 20:47:17.475 App_tab[298:207] '(null)' no such table: store (21)
```

the app continue work, but i have a lot of these errors...

**Please note that:**

- **don't have any sql database**
- **don't have any sql framework**
- **don't save data** on disk.

This problem come from today and i don't know a method to solve it!

EDIT: Ah, **it appears in all projects** that i open with my xcode!

Any idea?
It's very strange and i don't able to debug...

thanks,
alberto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you select the "Core data" option when creating the project, I suggest review the code that initializes the core data infrastructures in you application delegate, hope this fixes the error.

Comment: no, it now appears on all of my project that i have on mac. In any way that i create a project... I don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

Reset the simulator in the simulator menu.